# Is it possible to print page number on Report header in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have the latest version of Crystal Report (2012 ? I believe) and I am inserting a crosstab in the Report Header for summary. Everything is printing fine and correctly except the page number in the Page Footer (actual is the whole page footer where the page number was defined in) does not print.

If the crosstab has a lot of data and runs over multiple pages, the page footer will not print either until the report header section has finished.

For example, if the cross tab section run over to 2 pages, the footer will only print starting from page 3 and onward. The page numbering is correct but the footer will not print on the report header only. Is there a way to make Crystal report print out the footer in report header section? I think I can only put the cross tab in Report Header section as I only want it to print once. Putting it in page header will make it print each time there is a new page.

Comment: I don't think report is spanning multiple pages... it is extending the single page to fit the cross tab extension according to data. Also you can't put a cross tab in page header. it is only a single page that is getting extended to fit the cross tab...If you are sure of the cross tab maximum size then try to extend the design area using page setup option.

Comment: @Siva: Yes, I can control the width and limit it into 1 page. The rows though overflow to the next page. Even if it extends to the next page, the page number is accurate when the report header is done, continue to next page number and not start from 1.